# Метод OnEndDrag не отзывается, правильно ли я его использую?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Правильно ли оформлен метод? Если нет то как правильней?

```
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    didDrop = true;
}
```

Comment: добавь два события `OnBeginDrag` и `OnDrag` иначе не заработает

Comment: у тебя должны быть подключены все три интерфейса `IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler`

Comment: Правильно, вот только в каком контексте вы пытаетесь его использовать? Надеюсь хотя бы речь о UI.